# a query in sqlite on the first place in db

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to run a query on a DB that I've build but I have a strange problem
when I run the query ( by name ) and extract the result .
if I extract the first row in db than I can run another query on with other parameters.
if I extract a row other than the first I can no longer access to the first row in my db

```
    Cursor cur =datasource.query( 2,new String[] {"_id","Player","Num_of_wrong_ans","Num_of_drunkness_checks"} , PlayerDatabaseHelper.PLAYER + " =? " ,new String[] {array[1]} , null ); 
            if(cur.moveToFirst())
            {                   
                id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PlayerDatabaseHelper.ID));

            }
            cur.close();
```

the query method is this :

```
    public Cursor query( int indicator,String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String a;
    switch (indicator) 
    { 
    case 1: 
        qb.setTables(PlayerDatabaseHelper.PLAYER_TABLE_NAME); 
        qb.setProjectionMap(projectionMap); 
        break; 
    case 2: 
        qb.setTables(PlayerDatabaseHelper.PLAYER_TABLE_NAME); 
        qb.setProjectionMap(projectionMap); 
        qb.appendWhere(PlayerDatabaseHelper.PLAYER);
        break; 
    default: 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown  "); 
    } 

    // Get the database and run the query 
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null); 
    return c; 

}
```

what am I doing wrong ???

Comment: O.K.
I mean when I run a query on the first value in my db and than try to run if(cur.moveToFirst()) I receive false. i think it mean I receive an empty query

Comment: Please put that information into the question. Also, please show your table structure, and some example records, and a search value that fails.